# Check if popup is closed in phone-friendly way (Checking value of .closed doesn't work)

Tags: javascript, android

If I have created a popup window using `newWindow = window.open(url, name, dimensions)`, how can I check whether the window is closed in a way that will work on mobile browsers?

I tried using `if(newWindow.closed)`, and this works in Chrome on a PC and works on iPhone. However, on the Android phones I have tested on, this doesn't work; the popup closes but newWindow.closed is not true. **What test should I use instead that will work on any platform to check if a popup is closed?**

Extra info:
I used [jsconsole](http://jsconsole.com/?%3Alisten) to log newWindow (with `console.log(newWindow)`) before and after the popup was closed when visiting my page on an Android phone. While the popup window is open, it shows up in the console as `[object DOMWindow]`, and once the window is closed `console.log(newWindow)` just prints a blank line to the jsconsole. Note that printing a blank line is distinct from how jsconsole displays `null`, `undefined` or `false`, which show up exactly as I just typed them. Furthermore, trying `if(newWindow.closed || !newWindow)` works no better than just `if(newWindow.closed)` did; it seems that whatever kind of object `newWindow` becomes after the popup is closed, it is still truthy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Checking `if(newWindow.closed != false)` instead of `if(newWindow.closed)` solved my problem and works on all platforms I have tested on. The cause of the issue appears to be that on some Android phones, the value of `newWindow.closed` ends up being `undefined` instead of `true` when the popup window is closed. `newWindow.closed` is reliably set to `false` while the window is open, though, whatever platform you're on.

Some relevant discussion that potentially explains the reasons behind this bug can be found here (although I can't confirm its veracity):
http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=21061